# GNU Radio for windows. CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

Tags: cmake, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, cmakelists-options

All operations I'm doing on windows using GNU Radio Companion.
Before that I downloaded CMake archive cmake-3.29.0-rc4-windows-x86_64 and wrote path to bin folder in system path variable (in cmd cmake command is working).

I dowloaded example of [GRC file](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-dtv/examples/dvbt_rx_8k.grc). It's flowgraph of the GRC file:
[image]

I attempt execute it with C++ No GUI option:
[image]

As a result, I'm getting follow error:

```
Generating: "D:\progs\GRC_GNURadio\dvbt_rx_demo_8k"
>>> Warning: The block 'blocks_throttle_0' is deprecated.

Executing: cmake .. && cmake --build . -j7 && cd ../.. && None -e D:\progs\GRC_GNURadio\dvbt_rx_demo_8k/build/dvbt_rx_demo_8k

-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (project):
  Running

   'nmake' '-?'

  failed with:

   no such file or directory

CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

>>> Done (return code 1)
```

Auto generated CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

project(dvbt_rx_demo_8k)

find_package(Gnuradio "3.10" COMPONENTS
    blocks
    fec
    ... //another blocks
    soapy
)

add_executable(dvbt_rx_demo_8k dvbt_rx_demo_8k.cpp)
target_link_libraries(dvbt_rx_demo_8k
    gnuradio::gnuradio-blocks
    gnuradio::gnuradio-fft
    gnuradio::gnuradio-dtv
)
```

After first execution, I attempted change option Creating CMake to off and added following lines before project() function in previously (in the first execution) auto generated CMakeLists.txt:

```
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/pathto/g++" )
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/pathto/gcc" )
```

But it caused another error:

```
Generating: "D:\progs\GRC_GNURadio\dvbt_rx_demo_8k"
>>> Warning: The block 'blocks_throttle_0' is deprecated.

Executing: cmake .. && cmake --build . -j7 && cd ../.. && None -e D:\progs\GRC_GNURadio\dvbt_rx_demo_8k/build/dvbt_rx_demo_8k

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (project):
  Running

   'nmake' '-?'

  failed with:

   no such file or directory


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

>>> Done (return code 1)
```

Then I added CXX in the end of project name in project() function. But got same error.

Executing flowgraph with Python option then execution is finished successful.

Comment: Do you have a C and C++ compiler installed?  Are they in `PATH` when you use cmake's gui?  When you added them explicitly, is `nmake` available via `PATH`?

Comment: @StephenNewell, Now I got installed g++ and gcc, whote paths to it in PATH system var. Downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 Commynity for get nmake.exe file and wrote path to it in PATH. 
But I again got error CMAKE_***_COMPILER not set.
Then, I change CMakeList.txt file as:
```cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)```

```set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)```
```set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe" )```
```set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe" )```

```project(dvbt_rx_demo_8k CXX)```
But I again got same error related to line with project() function.

Comment: "But I again got same error related to line with project() function." - There are **plenty different errors** which could be emitted for a `project()` line and be about the compiler. So your statement alone is not sufficient for debug the error. The error message in your current post is about `nmake` utility, so I pointed (via "duplicate" mark) to the question and answers about the same problem. If you have another error, you may update the question post. But firstly make sure that you have **searched** for that another error.